# Kubernetes API Exception With No Info At All

Tags: java, kubernetes

I've been getting this issue a lot recently. My java app talks to kubernetes api to create a pod, but an exception was thrown with no message, no cause, and no clue on what is happening.

The exception I got:

```
io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: 
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:989)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:905)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.createNamespacedPodWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:7964)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.createNamespacedPod(CoreV1Api.java:7937)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at net.craftanvil.proxycore.manager.KubernetesPodManager.create(KubernetesPodManager.java:42)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at net.craftanvil.proxycore.service.impl.ServerManagementServiceImpl.createServer(ServerManagementServiceImpl.java:28)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at net.craftanvil.proxycore.Test.reg(Test.java:18)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at net.craftanvil.proxycore.Main.registerListeners(Main.java:105)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at net.craftanvil.proxycore.Main.onProxyInitialization(Main.java:79)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at net.craftanvil.proxycore.Lmbda$1.execute(Unknown Source)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at com.velocitypowered.proxy.event.UntargetedEventHandler$VoidHandler.lambda$buildHandler$0(UntargetedEventHandler.java:56)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at com.velocitypowered.proxy.event.VelocityEventManager.fire(VelocityEventManager.java:597)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at com.velocitypowered.proxy.event.VelocityEventManager.lambda$fire$5(VelocityEventManager.java:478)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[04:25:06 ERROR]:  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

and here is KubernetesPodManager:

```
    public void create(ServerTemplate template) {
        try {
            CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();

            V1Pod pod = new V1Pod()
                    .apiVersion("v1")
                    .kind("Pod")
                    .metadata(new V1ObjectMeta().name(template.getID()))
                    .spec(new V1PodSpec()
                            .addContainersItem(new V1Container()
                                    .name("server")
                                    .image("user/image") 
                                    .env(Arrays.asList(
                                            new V1EnvVar()
                                                    .name("POD_IP")
                                                    .valueFrom(new V1EnvVarSource()
                                                            .fieldRef(new V1ObjectFieldSelector().fieldPath("status.podIP"))),
                                            new V1EnvVar()
                                                    .name("SERVER_ID")
                                                    .value(template.getID())
                                    ))));

            api.createNamespacedPod("default", pod, null, null, null, null); <-- line 42
        } catch (ApiException exception) {
            //TODO: cannot create
            exception.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Exception when creating Pod: " + exception.getMessage() + exception.getCause() + exception.getCode() + Arrays.toString(exception.getStackTrace()));
        }
    }
```